# Finding The Total Sum of Multiplied List Indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newer to Python and I can't seem to figure out the logic for what I am trying to do. I have 11 lists. 10 lists contain the make and model of a car, followed by the value of each car, followed by the quantity of cars of each make/model. The 11th list contains the other 10 lists as one main list.

I'm trying to find the product of the value and quantity of each car within each of the 10 lists, then sum the 10 products to get a grand total of the total value of all the cars, and then print that value to the screen.

So far I have been able to find the index values that I need, multiply them together, and then print them individually to the screen. I added a counter variable that I was attempting to increment with the values of each calculated product until the end of the loop, at which point the function would stop and the final summed value would print, however this has only resulted with the final product printing to the screen or another number entirely.

I'll add examples for context.

My current code:

```
def totalValue(all):
    print("Total Value")
    x = 0
    for x in range(0, len(all)):
        i = (all[x][1])
        q = (all[x][2])
        iq = i * q
        # qi = iq + iq
        t = '${:,.2f}'.format(iq)
        print(t)
    return all


list0 = []
list1 = []
list2 = []

car1 = ["Chevy Bolt EV", 37495, 2]
car2 = ["Kia Niro", 24485, 23]
car3 = ["VW e-Golf", 32790, 12]
car4 = ["Hyundai Kona", 37495, 3]
car5 = ["Honda Insight", 23725, 4]
car6 = ["Chevrolet Volt", 34395, 14]
car7 = ["Hyundai Ioniq", 23285, 5]
car8 = ["Tesla Model 3", 45200, 1]
car9 = ["Audi e-tron", 75795, 2]
car10 = ["Toyota Prius", 24405, 12]

all = (car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6, car7, car8, car9, car10)

print()
totalValue(all)
```

What I would like to happen:

```
Total Value
$2,326,615.00
```

What I have now:

```
Total Value
$74,990.00
$563,155.00
$393,480.00
$112,485.00
$94,900.00
$481,530.00
$116,425.00
$45,200.00
$151,590.00
$292,860.00
```

I had this at one point thinking it should work:

```
def totalValue(all):
    print("Total Value")
    x = 0
    for x in range(0, len(all)):
        i = (all[x][1])
        q = (all[x][2])
        iq = i * q
        qi = iq + iq
    t = '${:,.2f}'.format(qi)
    print(t)
    return all
```

But it resulted in this:

```
Total Value
$585,720.00
```

I hope what I would like makes sense. I will clarify anything if need be. I have a feeling I am missing something rather obvious, but I can't tell what it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you make a mistake here: `qi = iq + iq`, you can try this:

```
def totalValue(all):
    print("Total Value")
    x = 0
    qi = 0
    for x in range(0, len(all)):
        i = (all[x][1])
        q = (all[x][2])
        iq = i * q
        qi += iq
    t = '${:,.2f}'.format(qi)
    print(t)
    return all
```

and the answer will be `$2,326,615.00`

---

or use `sum` here:

```
qi = sum(v[1] * v[2] for v in all)
print('${:,.2f}'.format(qi))
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. I think I see what I did now. I didn't set the initial value of qi to 0 before attempting to increment it. Is that correct?

Comment: and I think another problem is you mispell the `qi` to `iq` in `qi = iq + iq`, I think you means `qi = qi + iq`@Dev-MDW2

Comment: I think you're right, however it doesn't seem to matter? The code ran and gave me the same answer regardless, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the items, each time adding the (value X quantity) of each car to the sum. Then, once the loop has finished and the sum has been calculated, print it. 
The code:

```
def totalValue(all):
    print("Total Value")
    qi = 0
    for x in range(0, len(all)):
        qi += (all[x][1] * all[x][2])
    print('${:,.2f}'.format(qi))

list0 = []
list1 = []
list2 = []

car1 = ["Chevy Bolt EV", 37495, 2]
car2 = ["Kia Niro", 24485, 23]
car3 = ["VW e-Golf", 32790, 12]
car4 = ["Hyundai Kona", 37495, 3]
car5 = ["Honda Insight", 23725, 4]
car6 = ["Chevrolet Volt", 34395, 14]
car7 = ["Hyundai Ioniq", 23285, 5]
car8 = ["Tesla Model 3", 45200, 1]
car9 = ["Audi e-tron", 75795, 2]
car10 = ["Toyota Prius", 24405, 12]

all = (car1, car2, car3, car4, car5, car6, car7, car8, car9, car10)

totalValue(all)
```

This works. This code printed this:

Total Value

$2,326,615.00

Comment: This code worked exactly as I needed also, and it cut down on the amount code, which is a bonus. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.